# Cannot open Zip file after creation with tar.exe

Tags: tar

I'm trying to use Tar.exe in a Windows 10 command prompt to zip an entire folder and its subdirectories into a .zip file.

After reading different answers on here and [this online help](https://ss64.com/nt/tar.html), so far I have the following:

```
tar.exe -cvzf "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Output.zip" "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFolder"
```

This appears to work within the command prompt (no errors and all files get listed).  The .zip file gets created on the Desktop but when I try to open it by double-clicking on it, I get this error:

> Windows cannot open the folder.
>
> The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFolder' is invalid.

I dragged the file into Notepad to see if there were any headers that might uncover the problem, but it looks like some kind of oriental affair...!

[image]

Can anyone advise what I've done wrong here please?

Comment: The problem is that the `tar` program doesn't create a zip archive. It uses a different format for its archive, and the compression used is different as well. Rename it as `Output.tar.gz` or `Output.tgz`.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks.  I thought this flag, *-z (Compress archive with gzip.)* would produce a valid zip file.  I was hoping to be able to open natively without downloading anything else, but Windows doesn't appear to natively support tar.gz files...  Any ideas?

Comment: If you want a zip archive, use a zip archiver. GZip, despite its name, isn't the same.

Comment: Okay.  Out of interest I don't suppose you know what Windows' "Send to Compressed (Zipped) Folder" uses under the hood?  I'm wondering if I can (ab)use that...

Comment: It creates a plain Zip archive.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. The generated .zip cannot be extracted using Explorer's built-in "Extract to" functionality, but `tar -xf` works fine though. Not ideal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much deliberation, I finally opted to use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/):

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFolder.zip" "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyFolder"
```

The destination machine without 7-Zip could still read the file, but more importantly, the speed of the zip creation was magnitudes faster than Windows's UI or the Tar function.